# ReactJS: How to determine if the application is being viewed on mobile or desktop browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In ReactJS, is there a way to determine if the website is being viewed on mobile or desktop? Because, depending on which device I would like to render different things.

Thank you

Comment: I am not cool with a lot of answers, that just depend on the screen width. If you go to landscape mode for example, I still want to distinguish between a phone and a desktop version, especially with the control capabilities.

A clean setup should be able to distinguish between:
mobile/tablet/desktop
portrait/landscape
touch/no touch
keys/nokeys

least but not last pixel based breakpoints

Answer (score 196):

Simple solution using react hooks

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState<number>(window.innerWidth);

function handleWindowSizeChange() {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
}
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
    }
}, []);

const isMobile = width <= 768;
```

Comment: Simple and not depending on a package, this should be higher

Comment: Does this wait for the page to load since is using window/useEffect combination? In that case I think it's going to cause a visible layout shift. Do the libraries listed below work any different? I have a layout shift problem detecting window size in React

Comment: It would be better to have the state save a boolean "isMobile" or something like that. With this current solution it would re-render on every size change, where you probably only want to re-render, when it switches between mobile and desktop view.

Comment: I don't think using innerWidth is best. What about android devices that have very large inner width.

Comment: Doesn't work in landscape!

Comment: This just detects if the screen size is smaller than 769px. This has nothing to do with detecting if it's a mobile or not... Maybe OP needed to detect a "small screen", but still...

Comment: window inside the useState intial state will throw error undefined in a js environment, you may want to set it to 0 instead

Answer (score 120):

You can use [React Device Detect Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect)

This package uses the `user-agent` of the browser rather than the screen size.

This can be helpful when wanting to display different things if on desktop vs mobile or certain links based on the device

### Installation

To install, you can use npm or yarn:

```sh
# For NPM:
npm install react-device-detect --save

# For Yarn
yarn add react-device-detect
```

### Usage

Example:

```js
import {BrowserView, MobileView} from 'react-device-detect';

const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <BrowserView>
                <h1>This is rendered only in browser</h1>
            </BrowserView>
            <MobileView>
                <h1>This is rendered only on mobile</h1>
            </MobileView>
        </>
    );
};
```

if you don't need a view, you can use `isMobile` for conditional rendering

```js
import {isMobile} from 'react-device-detect';

const MyComponent = () => {
    if(isMobile) {
        return (
            <div> This content is available only on mobile</div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div> content... </div>
    );
};
```

> Taken from [React Device Detect README](https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect#readme) with a little modification

Comment: The React Device Detect Package works perfectly fine, the only problem is that it doesnt detect whenever the user resize the page.

Comment: when we have window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight why should we use this package? What is the benefit?

Comment: Because this is based on user agent rather than window size, I used it to display relevant link app in case it's displayed in desktop or iOS is Android

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify that difference

Comment: Doesn't work in landscape!

Comment: Can i check with tab ?

Answer (score 38):

I further enhanced Volobot's answer. I'd created a hook as below and it works like charm :)

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const useCheckMobileScreen = () => {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
    const handleWindowSizeChange = () => {
            setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
        }
    }, []);

    return (width <= 768);
}

export default useCheckMobileScreen
```

Answer (score 24):

What you are looking for is called `react-responsive`. You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive)

Here is `how to use` quick guide from their repo:

```
var MediaQuery = require('react-responsive');

var A = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Device Test!</div>

        <MediaQuery minDeviceWidth={1224}>
          <div>You are a desktop or laptop</div>
        </MediaQuery>
        <MediaQuery maxDeviceWidth={1224}>
          <div>You are a tablet or mobile phone</div>
        </MediaQuery>

        <MediaQuery orientation='portrait'>
          <div>You are portrait</div>
        </MediaQuery>
        <MediaQuery orientation='landscape'>
          <div>You are landscape</div>
        </MediaQuery>

        <MediaQuery minResolution='2dppx'>
          <div>You are retina</div>
        </MediaQuery>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Tablets has big screens but they act like mobile phones, so if you want to detect touch screen instead of the size of the screen:

```
const isTouchScreenDevice = () => {
    try{
        document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
        return true;
    }catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Why to complicate things when you can use one line of vanilla javascript code?

Use `window.screen` object to get width of current screen. For example `window.screen.width` will return value of current width of client in pixels.

Use it inside `if (window.screen.width >= 1280) { /* conditional statements */ }`

I hope that it helps. Thank you :-)

Comment: I think if you're going to be checking whether or not it's mobile size in a variety of places, there's something to be said for abstracting it into a hook so that you don't have redundancy in your code. If you're sure the check is a one-off though, this approach seems reasonable.

Answer (score 11):

Create a Custom Hook and Listen to Resize, load, orientationchange and reload will rerender the component where you have used this hook.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useIsMobile = (breakpoint = 640) => {
  const checkForDevice = () => window.innerWidth < breakpoint;

  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(checkForDevice());

  useEffect(() => {
    const handlePageResized = () => {
      setIsMobile(checkForDevice());
    };

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.addEventListener('resize', handlePageResized);
      window.addEventListener('orientationchange', handlePageResized);
      window.addEventListener('load', handlePageResized);
      window.addEventListener('reload', handlePageResized);
    }

    return () => {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handlePageResized);
        window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', handlePageResized);
        window.removeEventListener('load', handlePageResized);
        window.removeEventListener('reload', handlePageResized);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return {
    isMobile,
  };
};

export default useIsMobile;
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this method for React and it works great in 2020. Thanks @Anubahav Gupta

```
npm install react-responsive --save
```

Then create component:

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import MediaQuery from 'react-responsive';

class MyMediaQuery extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div>Device Test!</div>

                <MediaQuery minDeviceWidth={1224}>
                    <div>You are a desktop or laptop</div>
                </MediaQuery>
                <MediaQuery maxDeviceWidth={1224}>
                    <div>You are a tablet or mobile phone</div>
                </MediaQuery>

                <MediaQuery orientation='portrait'>
                    <div>You are portrait</div>
                </MediaQuery>
                <MediaQuery orientation='landscape'>
                    <div>You are landscape</div>
                </MediaQuery>

                <MediaQuery minResolution='2dppx'>
                    <div>You are retina</div>
                </MediaQuery>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default MyMediaQuery;
```

It works as-is on any page loaded but can also be imported into another file with:

```
import MyMediaQuery from '.newFileName';
```

Then used anywhere as:

```
<MyMediaQuery />
```

Answer (score 4):

We can make a simple custom hook which leverages [Interaction Media Features](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mf-interaction) using the [MatchMedia API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

```
function useDeviceDetect() {
  const [isTouchDevice, setIsTouchDevice] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!window.matchMedia) return;
    setIsTouchDevice(window.matchMedia("(pointer:coarse)").matches);
  }, []);

  return isTouchDevice;
}
```

The idea here is to target devices based on their capabilities (as apposed to say, checking the width or resolution of the device/viewport which tend to be moving targets)

For touch devices, the accuracy of the primary input mechanism of the device is limited, so `(pointer:coarse)` would match.

## [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-glitter-46s5r5?file=/useDeviceDetect.js)

Here's an example usage:

```
function App() {
  const isTouchDevice = useDeviceDetect();
  console.log({ isTouchDevice });
  return (
    <div>{`I am ${isTouchDevice ? "" : "NOT"} a touch device`}</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not specifc to React but here is my js fonction:

```
export const isMobile = () => window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)").matches
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getNumberDesignRequest = screenWidth => {
  let numberDesignRequest = 20
  if (screenWidth >= 1280 && screenWidth < 1525) {
    numberDesignRequest = 21
  }
  
  return numberDesignRequest
}

const ScreenWidth = () => {
  const [screenWidth, setScreenWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      const { innerWidth } = window
      setScreenWidth(innerWidth)
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(handleResize, 1000))
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
  }, [])

  return screenWidth
}

const FuzzySearch = () => {
  const screenWidth = ScreenWidth()
const numberDesignRequest = getNumberDesignRequest(screenWidth)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to check the size of the screen

```
const width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
const MAX_WIDTH_FOR_MOBILE = 900;
```

Now check the width of the screen with the max width

```
return (
   width < MAX_WIDTH_FOR_MOBILE ? <Mobile /> : <Desktop />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to show a single button in mobile version and am a beginner in react so most of solutions didn't worked for me. I instead went with a simple css approach:

```html
 <button className="disblock_mobile">my data </button>
```

```css
.disblock_mobile{display: none;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .disblock_mobile{display: block;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of the top answer, but without using the `width` as the state, and updating it on every resize. This way the state is only updated when `window.innerWidth <= 768` changes.

```js
  const [ isMobile, setIsMobile ] = useState<boolean>(window.innerWidth <= 900);
  
  const handleResize = () => setIsMobile(window.innerWidth <= 900);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", () => handleResize);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in plain javascript:

```
let width = window.innerWidth;

function handleWindowSizeChange() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);

// This is to remove the event listener when the page is closed or navigated away from.
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
};

const isMobile = function() {
    return width <= 768;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom hook for this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useIsMobile = (width)=> {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(window.innerWidth <= width);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setIsMobile(window.innerWidth <= 768);
    }

    // Add event listener to window resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    // Clean up the event listener on component unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return isMobile;
}

export default useIsMobile;
```

here

You can use it in your component :
[You can use this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4C5t.png)

Answer (score 0):

If all you really want is

- to know if it's a mobile,
- you're ok with solution using screen size as a proxy,
- you don't care about window size updates, rotation, etc,

many other answers may be overengineered for your case. Here's a possible two-liner:

```js
const [width, height] = [window.screen.width, window.screen.height];
const isMobile = Math.min(width, height) < 768;
console.log(Math.min(width, height));
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers (apart from one that uses a package) all appear to simply be checking the screen width when determining if the client is mobile or not. Someone could be accessing from a tablet in landscape mode which would be a mobile device but be classified as desktop with that approach.

Here is an approach that uses the `user-agent` to classify the device as one of `Mobile`, `Tablet` or `Desktop`. Abstracted as a custom hook for convenience.

```
// hooks.js

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useDeviceType() {
  const [device, setDevice] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleDeviceDetection() {
      const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
      const isMobile = /iphone|ipad|ipod|android|windows phone/g.test(userAgent);
      const isTablet =
        /(ipad|tablet|playbook|silk)|(android(?!.*mobile))/g.test(userAgent);

      if (isMobile) setDevice('Mobile');
      else if (isTablet) setDevice('Tablet');
      else setDevice('Desktop');
    }

    handleDeviceDetection();
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleDeviceDetection);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleDeviceDetection);
  }, []);

  return device;
}
```

And then to implement it:

```
// app.js or wherever

const deviceType = useDeviceType();
console.log(deviceType);
// prints 'Mobile', 'Tablet' or 'Desktop' depending on device.
```

Answer (score -16):

React doesn't do this, React is only the View in MVC. Determination logic (controlling what SHOULD be viewed) is the role of the Controller. React doesn't implement a controller but thinks that should be done by the rest of the application, so you should add some other code controlling the context of the React component or even using different components for different devices.

Comment: So, how would you build a responsive page using React?

Comment: The same a non-react page, using media queries. React produces HTML in your browser, you can apply media queries to that.

Comment: "Determination logic (controlling what SHOULD be viewed) is the role of the Controller". Media queries are the controller?

Comment: No, media queries are part of css and thus styling. The contents created by control logic based of some model (information resource). @Anubhav Gupta suggested react-responsive which seems to act as a control layer to adjust the content

Comment: I think that @AnubhavGupta gave a good answer. However, your initial answer gave me the impression that it would be wrong to control with React which components should or not be viewed