# How to restrict users to use desktop view in mobiles (in React Js )

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an application which is optimized for desktop view. Is there any way to make the application warn users if they open it in mobile view and ask them to open it in desktop view ?

Answer (score 3):

In your root component,

```
const [showMobileWarning, setShowMobileWarning] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  if(window.innerWidth <= 800)
    setShowMobileWarning(true)
}, [])
```

Then use `showMobileWarning` to conditionally display warning message.

```
return(
    .........
    {showMobileWarning ? <SomeWarning />}
    .........
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to detect if the user is browsing your website on a mobile device is checking for the size of the screen. You can do this with JavaScript:

```js
const isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches;

if(isMobile){
  // Display message onto screen or do whatever you want
}
```

Here is a simple implementation in a React functional component:

```js
function displayOnlyOnDesktop() {
  const isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches;

  if(isMobile){
    return <div>Sorry, this website is only available on desktop devices.</div>
}
  return <div>Hooray, you're on a desktop device, so you can see this website!</div>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create a Warning Box, something that is an attention seeker, and then, need to detect the device width.

If the device width is in the range for a phone then, display the component.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435395/reactjs-how-to-determine-if-the-application-is-being-viewed-on-mobile-or-deskto) for details regarding fetching the inner-width.