# Best way to choose a component to be shown to the user based on screen size (react-app)

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design

I am working with a react app, and i have a list of items to be displayed. So i want to have a `<Items items={data}/>` component but the styling for `<Items items={data}/>` component in mobile-view and desktop-view is completely different, so i decided to make 2 components

```js
<MobileViewItems items ={data}/>
<DesktopViewItems items={data}/>
```

I only want to show one of these components based on screen size.

I know i can use css media queries to show or hide an element based on screen size and i searched online and found out about this package called
react-media: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media
react-media allows us to do this logic of choosing a component to show based on screen size in javascript.

Are there any other ways to solve this problem, and what is the best way to do it and why?

Assume that the data passed as props is huge, like an array of 5000 items.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty good answer here, you should check it out.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60932511/6912349

Short answer is there is a [React Device Detect Package library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect) to help you with this.

This library allows you to write code like this:

```
import {isMobile} from 'react-device-detect';

function App() {
  renderContent = () => {
    if (isMobile) {
      return <div> This content is available only on mobile</div>
    }
    return <div> ...content </div>
  }

  render() {
    return this.renderContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks great, Thank you. But what is the problem with doing it with css media queries will there be a performance issue since React has to render both MobileViewItems and DesktopViewItems ?

Comment: for performance issue you can use dynamic import