# How can I call a hook in mobile mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, floating

I imported a `useFloating` hook from `@floating-ui/react-dom.` And I only need it in **desktop** mode so extra rendering will happen in mobile mode. How can I call it only in desktop mode? Is memoize the right way?

```
const { x, y, reference, floating, strategy } = useFloating({
placement: "bottom-end",
strategy: "absolute",
middleware: [
  shift({ padding: 12 }),
  flip({
    fallbackPlacements: ["left-start", "left", "left-end"],
  }),
 ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Many methods available. IMO the best way is to create a breakpoint hook to be reused throughout the application. Here's a link demonstrating some methods to do this. [ReactJS: How to determine if the application is being viewed on mobile or desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435395/reactjs-how-to-determine-if-the-application-is-being-viewed-on-mobile-or-deskto)