# How to check if React app is being viewed on Desktop or Mobile

Tags: reactjs, mobile, state, page-size

Making a React App and need to have different functionality for Desktop and Mobile. So far I did this:

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(false);

const handleWindowSizeChange = () => {
        setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        if(width <= 500) {
            setMobile(true);
        } else setMobile(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
        }
    }, []);
```

But it's not working. I console logged the "mobile" state and it always logs "false" even tho i change the screen size in my browser. Especially if i reload my page while still being in mobile view. How do I make it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435395/reactjs-how-to-determine-if-the-application-is-being-viewed-on-mobile-or-deskto

Comment: Hi, that's the solution I tried but it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are two issues preventing this from working.

1. You're not setting `isMobile` to the correct value on initial page load. The handler looks reasonable for *updating* isMobile on resize, but if the window isn't resized, it won't be set correctly.
2. Within `handleWindowSizeChange`, you're using `width`, which hasn't been set to `window.innerWidth` yet.

My recommendation would be to get rid of the `width` state (unless you need it outside of getting `isMobile`). Your code could look something like:

```
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(window.innerWidth <= 500);

const handleWindowSizeChange = () => {
  setMobile(window.innerWidth <= 500);
}

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Andrew Hunt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74169433/12959962) returns an error with Next.js.

`error - ReferenceError: window is not defined`

The reason is by default Next.js does **server-side rendering**. This means that the content will be rendered **before accessing the browser**. Since the browser is not used while rendering the content, `window` of the browser will not be defined.

To overcome this, we can check if it's in mobile view once `window` is defined.

```js
const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(
    typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.innerWidth < 1024
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setIsMobile(window.innerWidth < 1024);
    }

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      handleResize();
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => {
      // remove event listener when the component is unmounted to not cause any memory leaks
      // otherwise the event listener will continue to be active
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  // add `isMobile` state variable as a dependency so that
  // it is called every time the window is resized
  }, [isMobile]);
```